# Spring inject a bean into another bean

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject a bean into another bean that uses it. How can I do this?

```
public class MySpringConfig{
@Bean
public MyObject getMyObject() {
  //.....

  return MyObjectInstance;
}



@Bean
public SomeObject getSomeObject(MyObject myObject) {

  //.....

  return SomeObjectInstance;
 }    
}
```

Comment: Did you actually try this code? Doesn't this work?

Comment: You can try adding {@Autowire} annotation to getSomeObject method parameter which injects your bean

Comment: As @lealceldeiro pointed out, your code should work if some constraints are met. If it is not working, you should name the param object the same as the `@Bean` method you need, in your case, it should be `getSomeObject(MyObject getMyObject)`

Answer (score 4):

I think you can do this with this way, this is working in my project.

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

 @Bean
 public Bean1 foo(@Qualifier("bean2") Bean2 bean2) {
  return new Bean1(bean2);
 }

}
```

Comment: what do we pass if we want to call it manually? for instance                   AppConfig appConfig=new AppConfig();
Bean1 myBean=appConfig.foo();//what do we pass as Param here?
and I want to get the same object each time when I do appConfig.foo()?

Answer (score 4):

i think that might work!

```
 @Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

  @Bean
  public Bean2 bean2() {
      return new Bean2();
  }

  @Bean
  @DependsOn({"bean2"})
  public Bean1 foo(@Autowired Bean2 bean2) {
     return new Bean1(bean2); // or your can write new Bean1(bean2());
  }
```

}

Comment: `@DependsOn` and `@Autowired` are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters don't work exactly in the same way in `@Bean` and `@Component`.
For a class annotated with `@Component`, specifying them is required for the autowired constructor but in a `@Bean` declaration you don't need to provide a parameter to specify the `MyObject` dependency to use (while it will work) if that is accessible in the current class, which is your case.
So you want to inject directly the bean by invoking `getMyObject()` in the @Bean definition.
For example to pass it a constructor arg :

```
@Bean
public SomeObject getSomeObject() {

  //....
  // you injected MyObject in the current bean to create
  SomeObject object = new SomeObject(getMyObject());
  //...
  return SomeObjectInstance;     
}
```

And don't forget to annotate the class with `@Configuration` to make it considered by Spring.