Azure Application Insight With Spring Boot | Custom Telemetry Initializer
I am trying to use azure application insights with spring boot application. Below is my code
I am using
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.4</version>
</dependency>

I need a CustomTelemetryInitializer, where I can change the operation id with my value.
package com.example.demo;

import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.TelemetryInitializer;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.Telemetry;

public class MyCustomTelemetryInitializer implements TelemetryInitializer {

    @Override
    public void initialize(Telemetry telemetry) {
        // Add custom properties to telemetry
        telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId("my-correlation-id");
    }
}

I am trying to register this CustomTelemetryInitializer like this
package com.example.demo;

import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryConfiguration;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.extensibility.TelemetryInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class AppInsightsConfig {
    @Bean
    public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
        return new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
    }

    @Bean
    public TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration(TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer, CustomTelemetryProcessor customTelemetryProcessor) {
        TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.createDefault();
        
        configuration.getTelemetryInitializers().add(myCustomTelemetryInitializer);
        
        return configuration;
    }

    @Bean
    public TelemetryClient telemetryClient(TelemetryConfiguration telemetryConfiguration) {
        return new TelemetryClient(telemetryConfiguration);
    }
}



This is my rest endpoint
package com.example.demo;

import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.TelemetryClient;
import com.microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetry.RequestTelemetry;
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyController {

    private final TelemetryClient telemetryClient;

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String sayHello() {
        RequestTelemetry requestTelemetry = new RequestTelemetry();
        telemetryClient.trackRequest(requestTelemetry); // this calls MyCustomTelemetryInitializer.initialize()
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}


Issue is, when I hit this endpoint MyCustomTelemetryInitializer.initialize() doesn't get invoked automatically, which I am expecting.
On manually doing telemetryClient.trackRequest(requestTelemetry) that gets invoked.
I want MyCustomTelemetryInitializer.initialize() to be invoked for all telemetry application sends so that I can set my operation id for them.
For ASP.NET I see this approached suggested in documentation. No mention for Java.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling?tabs=dotnet%2Cjavascriptwebsdkloaderscript#addmodify-properties-itelemetryinitializer
What am I missing? Is there any better way to achieve my goal?

To inject a custom bean at the startup, you should use
@Bean
public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
    return new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
}

In which just the constructor of MyCustomTelemetryInitializer is being executed. To call a specific method after the construct you can do it "manually"
@Bean
public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
    MyCustomTelemetryInitializer foo = new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
    foo.initialize(...);
    return foo;
}

To do it automatically, use this annotation @PostConstruct
public class MyCustomTelemetryInitializer implements TelemetryInitializer {

    @PostConstruct
    public void fooBar(Telemetry telemetry) {
        telemetry.getContext().getOperation().setId("my-correlation-id");
    }
}

So, you can inject the bean in a more simple way
@Bean
public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
    return new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
}

Complex setup
If your method to be called at the startup needs a complex settings, just do it before
@Bean
public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {

    Telemetry telemetry = new ...
    //telemetry.setFoo
    //telemetry.setBar

    MyCustomTelemetryInitializer foo = new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
    foo.initialize(telemetry);
    return foo;
}

Instantiated by a framework
If the dependency of Bean1 is Bean2 but you can't instantiate it manually because some library already did it, you can use @Autowire
@Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Telemetry defaultTelemetry;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"defaultTelemetry"})
    public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer() {
        MyCustomTelemetryInitializer foo = new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
        foo.initialize(defaultTelemetry);
        return foo;
    }
}

Depends on
If to instantiate a Bean1 you need another instance like Bean2 but Bean2 is another bean instantiated manually by you in the same project, you can use this annotation @DependsOn:
@Configuration
 public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Telemetry defaultTelemetry() {
        return new Telemetry(...);
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn({"defaultTelemetry"})
    public TelemetryInitializer myCustomTelemetryInitializer(@Autowired Telemetry foo) {
        MyCustomTelemetryInitializer foo = new MyCustomTelemetryInitializer();
        foo.initialize(foo);
        return foo;
    }
}  

References

https://stackoverflow.com/a/57463795/3957754
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5419722/3957754
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html


Question is not about how to make dependency injection work. It's specifically about how to add custom data in azure app insight telemetry.

#1 The only occurrence of "data" is in the previous comment  o_0 #2 The issue in your own words was: >> Issue is, when I hit this endpoint MyCustomTelemetryInitializer.initialize() doesn't get invoked automatically  #3 To solve it you need to understand how D.I, spring , constructors and java works
